# JS/jQuery delay loop to get desire result (delay() not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, delay

I'm trying to create an loading icon by moving the css 'background-position' of an image in a loop:

```
$('#LoginButton').click(function () {

    var i = 1, h = 0, top;

    for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        h = i * 40;
        top = h + 'px';
        $('#ajaxLoading').css('background-position', '0 -' + top).delay(800);
    }

});
```

The problem here is that it runs to fast so I don't se the 'animation' of the moving background.
So I added jquerys delay(), but:

delay(800) is not working because delay() only works in jquery animation effects and .css() is not one of those.

How to delay this loop?

Comment: would you mind commenting on my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using jQuery timer plugin: http://jquery.offput.ca/js/jquery.timers.js

```
$('#LoginButton').click(function () {
    var times = 13;
    var delay = 300;
    var h = 0, top;
    $(document).everyTime(delay, function(i) {
        top = h + 'px';
        $('#ajaxLoading').css('background-position', '0 -' + top);
        h += 40;
    }, times);
});
```

In case you don't want any plugins, use setInterva/clearInterval:

```
$('#LoginButton').click(function () {
    var delay = 300;
    var times = 13;
    var i = 0, h = 0, top;

    doMove = function() {
        top = h + 'px';
        $('#ajaxLoading').css('background-position', '0 -' + top);
        h += 40;

        ++i;
        if( i >= times ) {
            clearInterval( interval ) ;
        }
    }

    var interval = setInterval ( "doMove()", delay );
});
```

Comment: This is great!  St. Woland, you saved me a lot of grief.  Note to nubes: the delay var is in milliseconds.. so if you want to convert that to seconds, do this: var interval = setInterval("doMove()", delay*1000);

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() and clearTimeout() functions in order to accomplish that.

IE:

```
var GLOBAL_i = 0;

function doAnimation() {

    var h = GLOBAL_i * 40;
    var top = h + 'px';
    $('#ajaxLoading').css('background-position', '0 -' + top);

    if (GLOBAL_i < 12) {
        GLOBAL_i++;

        t=setTimeout(doAnimation, 800);
    }
}

$('#LoginButton').click(function () {

    doAnimation()

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using animate() instead of css()? I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, so this is kinda a shot in the dark.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I don't want to animate because I will see the background moving. I want it to 'jump' so I use css.

Comment: In that case, you will need to define a function which changes the position of the element as you have above, and then call it with setTimeout(). Then once the loading is finished, call clearTimeout() on the defined timer to keep it from continuing to run.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, Safari and IE3+ should support background-position-y, so if you're targeting these specific browser, using jquery you could just make a timed `animation()` on `backgroundPositionY` property - http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y
(On Firefox the effect won't work)